# String to date on GDS / BIGQUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

halo, i had data that write with -> 27-Sep-2022 | 15:12
how to make it be date on bigquery?
i have try formatdate, substr, and parsedate but none can. thank you!

Comment: are you trying to create, update or?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Below example should give you an ideas of your options (at least few of them)

```
with  your_table as (
  select '27-Sep-2022 | 15:12' col
)
select col, 
  date(parse_datetime('%d-%B-%Y | %H:%M', col)), 
  parse_date('%d-%B-%Y', trim(split(col, '|')[offset(0)]))
from your_table
```

with output

[image]